# Angular material table custom filter

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using mat-table. I know about the build in filter. And the `filterPredicate`. But filter predicate only accepts `filterValue: string`. I want to be able to filter the table with slide toggle and show only objects that have for example `isActive` flag true or `isActive` flag false. But default filter doesn't offer such functionality.  I figured out some workarounds myself but I hope there is a better solution. 
 
1) I can filter the array myself but in that way I need to keep the initial array and pass the filtered array to the table. And I don't like the idea of using two arrays for the same information. 
2) I can pass special value to the filter when slide toggle is changed for example `&@changedToggle-true` and check for that value in the filter predicate and filter only objects with the right isActive flag. But that still doesn't look like good solution to me. 
Is there any good way for achieving what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if I understand your problem, but you can extends standard datasource with something like this:

```
YourCustomDatasource extends Datasource<YourObject> {
 private objects: Observable<Obj[]>;

  filterCustom() {
   return objects.filter(elem => elem.isActive)
   .map(elem => elem)
   .subscribe(
    err => console.error(err),
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you explain me how is this objects property set. It throws me exception that objects is undefined.